# Nifi Processor gets triggered twice for single Input flow file

Tags: apache-nifi

I am currently new on Apache Nifi and still exploring it.
I made a custom processor where I will fetch data from server with pagination.
I pass the input file which will contains the attribute "url".
Finally transfer the response in output flow file, as I fetch data with pagination, so I made a new output flow file for each page and transferred it to Successful relationship.
Below is the code part:

```
@Override
public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {
    FlowFile incomingFlowFile = session.get();
    String api = null;
    if (incomingFlowFile == null) {
        logger.info("empty input flow file");
        session.commit();
        return;
    } else {
       api=incomingFlowFile.getAttribute("url");
    }

    session.remove(incomingFlowFile);
    if(api == null) {
        logger.warn("API url is null");
        session.commit();
        return;
    }

    int page = Integer.parseInt(context.getProperty(PAGE).getValue());

    while(page < 3) {
        try {
            String url = api + "&curpg=" + page;
            logger.info("input url is: {}", url);
            HttpResponse response = httpGetApiCall(url, 10000);
            if(response == null || response.getEntity() == null) {
                logger.warn("response null");
                session.commit();
                return;
            }

            String resp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(StandardCharsets.UTF_16.encode(resp).array());
            FlowFile outFlowFile = session.create();
            outFlowFile = session.importFrom(is, outFlowFile);
        session.transfer(outFlowFile, SUCCESSFUL);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.warn("IOException :{}", e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        ++page;
    }
    session.commit();
}
```

I am facing issue that for a single Input flow file, this processor get triggered twice and so it generates 4 flow files for a single input flow file.

I am not able to figure out this where I have done wrong.
Please help in this issue.
Thanks in advance.

======================================================================
[processor group 1(Nifi_Parvin)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAxS2.png)

[processor group 2 (News_Point_custom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1uIB.png)

Comment: i don't see clear error in your code. but it's  possible to implement this logic using standard nifi processors `DuplicateFlowFile -> InvokeHTTP`

Comment: logic with `page` variable is unclear: `while(page < 3) { ++page }`

Comment: @daggett: page is used as a parameter in API , for example https://test.com&curpg=page, I want to loop over the API ( https://test.com&curpg=page)  for page value (1,2,3... so on).

Comment: right, but you init `page` variable with attribute value from the context (not from flowfile). so looks like it's not 0 or 1. what is the initial value? i advice you to add logging to understand what's wrong in your code...

Comment: I able to solve the issue, but still don't know the reason why it happened.
Issue occurs in below flow:
Process Group 1 : 
GenerateInputFlowFile ---- input Port 1 -----> RPG
input Port 1 ---> Process group 2

Process group 2 :
input ---> custom proessor


when I moved custom processor to process group 1 instead of keeping it in process group 2, it worked fine.

Comment: Added snapshots for references